# change selectedindex from viewstack from child customcomponent

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I have a viewstack, which contains 3 (at this moment just 1) customcomponents:

```
<s:Application xmlns:components="components.*">
    <mx:ViewStack id="mainViewStack" x="76" y="90" width="800" height="400">
        <components:Login />
    </mx:ViewStack>
</s:Application>
```

(removed some code for readability)
This is done correct, and also everything inside the component works correctly

In this function (inside the custom component) he should change the selectedIndex of the viewstack if the condition is met (which happens):

```
protected function checkUsernameExistsDbSucces(event:ResultEvent):void
{
    if(Boolean(event.result) != 0)
    {
        this.parentApplication.mainViewStack.selectedIndex = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        some code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the "parent" property to walk back to the view stack.  Here is some example code.  For simplicity i didn't code up and example custom component, but the parent references should still work even from inside your custom component where the handlers would be in your situation.

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        protected function back_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ViewStack(btnBack.parent.parent).selectedIndex = 0;
        }

        protected function forward_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ViewStack(btnForward.parent.parent).selectedIndex = 1;
        }

    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:ViewStack id="viewstack1" x="476" y="97" width="200" height="200">
    <mx:Canvas width="100%" height="100%" label="View 1">
        <mx:Button x="125" y="168" id="btnForward" label="forward" click="forward_clickHandler(event)"/>
    </mx:Canvas>
    <mx:Canvas width="100%" height="100%" label="back">
        <mx:Button x="137" y="168" id="btnBack" label="back" click="back_clickHandler(event)"/>
    </mx:Canvas>
</mx:ViewStack>
```

But I wouldn't suggest this since you are trying to affect an component which resides outside your custom component.  And this solution would require that your custom component is always positioned so that the second parent object is always a ViewStack.  Of course you could validate and only perform the action if you can find a viewstack as the second parent, but we are definitely breaking the idea of a "custom component" in that you can use the component anytime anywhere regardless of what is going on outside the component.

So I'd suggest using events to trigger the change in the viewstack.  So inside your component, you'd create a custom event.  And throw it when the conditions are met. Then you can listen to that event and change the selectedIndex of the viewstack.

Here's Adobe's documentation on creating custom events:

[Dispatching custom events](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=createevents_3.html)